# Android Studio, чтение из БД с условием WHERE, результат не соответствует ожиданиям

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Написал метод, который возвращает значения tittle, description и reward из таблицы achievements, где user_id = id (например, user_id = 1), но он возвращает лишь одну запись (самую первую), когда их в БД 26. Если убрать условие `WHERE`, то возвращает все 26 записей.

Вот код метода:

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getAchievements(Context context) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> achievementsList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap;

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    databaseHelper.create_db();
    db = databaseHelper.open();

    String query = String.format("SELECT \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\" FROM \"%s\" WHERE \"%s\" = \"%s\"", COLUMN_TITTLE,
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_REWARD, TABLE_ACHIEVEMENTS, COLUMN_USERS_ID, id);
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put(TITTLE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITTLE))); // Название
        hashMap.put(DESCRIPTION, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION))); // Описание
        hashMap.put(REWARD, "Get " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_REWARD)) + "$"); // Вознаграждение
        achievementsList.add(hashMap);
    }
    cursor.close();

    db.close();

    return achievementsList;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему такое может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я перепутал переменную COLUMN_USERS_ID, которая содержит _id, с COLUMN_ID_USER, в которой id_user, поэтому у меня условие работало _id = 1, т.е. выводило первую запись. Для юзера с _id=2, выводило 2-ую запись и т.д.